# Table not created when @EmbeddedId has an extra String property

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I'm trying to automatically generate the table for following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gas_price")
class GasPrice(
  @EmbeddedId
  var id: GasPriceId,
  var price: Double,
)

@Embeddable
class GasPriceId(
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  var gasStation: GasStation,
  var isSelf: Boolean,
  var readDate: Instant,
  var description: String
) : Serializable
```

As it is, the table is not generated on application launch, but if I remove

```
var description: String
```

the table does generate with correct values.

I am out of ideas on why it happens, anyone faced a similar issue?

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: No, no error messages at all

Answer (score 0):

Apparently inside @Embeddable for the String property I had to define the column length. So:

```
@Column(length = 200)
var description: String
```

and the table is generated. I'd have to look into why, but this solved my problem.